# Do Item Development unlocks persist in New Game +?

Tags: neptunia-v

One annoyance with Hyperdimension Mk2 was that when you started a new game plus you lost a *lot* of random progress, including unlocked item development items. You'd keep the recipe, but the items wouldn't be available in stores.

Has this changed? Do I only have to unlock item dev items once in Victory or will I have to craft them once per cycle to buy them at a store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Started new game plus today and it turns out unlocked items will remain in stores after a new game plus, unlike Mk2, so you'll only have to craft items once to buy them in stores.

Answer (score 1):

As like MK2, anything made available in the stores with the help of Item Dev will be removed when you go into NG+ so you will have to make them again.... You do get to keep the recipes.

Comment: Arg, was hoping they did away with that. Oh well.

Comment: Its not so bad. You get to keep all the items you had prior to the NG+ so a lot of the needed ingredients are readily available to start crafting.